# Use household 12 V DC adapter with RFID transponder?

Tags: current, ac, dc, rfid

Is it possible to use a common household 12 volt DC output adapter with this RFID transponder. I am a newbie but I am willing to learn. Here is a diagram of this RFID transponder system [image: diagram] of this.

http://i729.photobucket.com/albums/ww295/stealthmedal/6a2f9ff4.jpg

Wall wart: [image]

The product description is as follows (for those in need of additional information) :
The reciever operates on 12 VDC  Details: The key fob is completely waterproof, and crunch resistant. Size:l.4" square and is meant to be attached to your keychain and has a recessed circle to allow you to place a custom label (if desired). The sensor is about 2.1" x 1.3" and is attached by 20" cable to the 4 1/8" x 2 1/8" receiver box. The sensor can be mounted in wood, behind glass or plastic and still function perfectly. The sophisticated receiver uses 6 ICs and have 12V OUT PUT WHEN TRRIGER .  when the correct key fob is brought within 3 inches of the sensor. THE UNIT PUTS OUT 12V OUT PUT (MUST BE WIRED TO 12V REALAY), and when key removed from sensor relay will open.

Please help me.

Comment: You'll need to know the current draw of the device and the current capability of the 12 volt wall wart.

Comment: I've made an edit to the comment including pictures of the adapter.

Comment: What is the current draw of the RFID system and relay? Your drawing also isn't very clear. What does "-12v ground" mean. Is it -12v or is it ground?

Comment: So your wall wart can provide 300 milliamps of 12volts. What does your device and relay require? If the sum is less then you're ok.

Comment: This is not my drawing. It came with the product. I am trying to find out what these aspects of the drawing mean as well.

Comment: What is the product? Don't take me as being rude... but that drawing looks like something a 10 year old would make. Surely there is a better product to go with that makes real drawings with real current requirements.

Comment: It seems like it must be wired to  "12V relay".

Comment: No offense taken considering the fact that I did not create this diagram.

Comment: With the information given, you aren't going to be able to get any better answer than what Brian has given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's the drawing which came with the RFID reader, that's bad. It doesn't give me much hope for the details we really need to know. It should say what power the reader consumes, and what current the 12V output can supply. It suggests it can switch a relay, but that's useless. There are thousands of different relays, Digikey lists 1776 12V power relays. What load do you want to switch?
There's one which already switches at a 1.4mA coil current. I'm pretty sure you could use that, but it's a bit expensive. [This one](http://components.omron.com/components/web/PDFLIB.nsf/0/4F7D9D9CA026C97E862573930070AC4F/%24file/G5LA_E_0911.pdf) is inexpensive and needs 30mA, probably also within the ouput's possibilities. Depending on the version and type of load it can switch 5A to 10A.

The wall-wart says 12V 300mA, find out how much power the RFID reader needs, so that you know how much remains to power the relay. Then find out how much current the output can deliver. With this information you can select a suitable relay.

> "I am trying to find out what these aspects of the drawing mean as well."

The red and the black wire are the 12V DC coming from your wall wart. They supply the power to your RFID reader. The relay is also 12V, and uses the same ground (that green line should also be black). The yellow line is the output of the reader, it switches between 0V (off) and 12V (on). So connecting a relay between that output and ground will switch the relay on when the output is 12V.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same RFID reader (eBay) and can confirm that it will work with that DC adapter. I am a beginner myself, but that's the same input as mine (300 mA) and it works. The thing I'm having trouble with is wondering why you even need the relay in the first place if it's connected via a DC adapter to AC power? I thought relays were mainly used so batteries don't drain? Does this mean you wouldn't necessarily need one with this setup? I've used the RFID transponder to set off a small buzzer, and power a small LED, but once I connect the relay, nothing seems to work. I'm just not seeing the purpose of the relay in this setup (again, I'm a beginner and may be missing something pretty basic...)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, however as *kenny* said, you need its current requirement. As *user1299661* asked and *Kellenjb* asked above, the wall wart connects to -12 V DC in (positive) and what is labeled (-12V ground). I suspect -12V is "ground" for the +12 V DC in, not -12 V.

But again, check the manual for voltage and current required.

Comment: What exactly does the 12 volt description on the diagram detail?

Comment: Brian, the downvote isn't mine, but I do think you'll have to elaborate. OP doesn't seem to understand the diagram in the first place, I wonder if he knows what you mean by "current requirement". (Which makes me wonder why he accepted this)